# How to make div:before visible when overflow is set to scroll?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build a console in ReactJS. But when I try to insert a Console top bar, I have used before psuedo element for div 'Terminal'. But I wanted the div to be overflow scroll. When the div 'Terminal' is set to overflow:scroll the psuedoelement is not visible. How to make the Terminal::before make visible.

Here is the Css and JS code for the app;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      commandHistory:[],
      value:'',
      answer:'',

    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({
        value: e.target.value
      });
  }

  keyPress(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var inputelement=e.target.value;
        if(inputelement[0]=='s' || inputelement[1]=='i' || inputelement[2]=='n'){
          console.log('yes');
        }
        else if(inputelement[0]=='c' || inputelement[1]=='o' || inputelement[2]=='s'){
          console.log('yes');
        }
        else if(inputelement[0]=='t' || inputelement[1]=='a' || inputelement[2]=='n'){
          console.log('yes');
        }
        console.log(e.target.value);
        var newArray = this.state.commandHistory;
        newArray.push(e.target.value);
        //console.log(newArray);
        this.setState({
          commandHistory:newArray,
          value:''
        });

        var terminalOutput=document.getElementById('terminalOutput');
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('>>> '+e.target.value));
        var breakStatement= document.createElement("br");
        element.appendChild(breakStatement);
        try{
          var answer=eval(e.target.value);
        }
        catch(e){
          answer=inputelement+": Command not found"
        }
        console.log(answer);
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode( answer ));
        terminalOutput.append(element);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (



        <div className="Terminal">

          <div className="controls">
            <span className="red"></span><span className="yellow"></span><span className="green"></span><span>root@user:~ </span>
          </div>
          <div className="Terminal-machine">
            <div className="Input-Terminal">
              <span className="machine-name">root@user:~ calc<br/>
              &nbsp;Type "help","12+34", "(12+34)*76" for more information</span>
              <div id="terminalOutput"></div>&nbsp;>>> <input value={this.state.value} onKeyDown={this.keyPress} onChange={this.handleChange}  id="terminalInput" ></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



    );
  }
}


export default App;

body {
  background-color: #47CBA4;
  margin: 0;
  color:white;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: cursor, courier;

}

.Terminal{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #3B4350;
  top:50%;
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

}

.Terminal::before{
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(#4C505D, #3B4350);
  width: inherit;
  height:40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-40px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-bottom:2px solid #474A59;
  z-index: 1;
}
.controls span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width:15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  top:-25px;

}

.red{
  background-color: #D94D53;
}
.red:hover{
  background-color: #ce495c ;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: #EBBC58;
}
.yellow:hover{
  background-color: #dfb360;
}
.green{
  background-color: #61CA82;
}
.green:hover{
  background-color: #57b68e;
}

input#terminalInput {
  color: white;
  font-family: cursor, courier;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: none;
  width: 70%;
}
.machine-name{
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  position: relative;
}
input#terminalInput::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
#terminalOutput{
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: block;

}
```

Comment: Since you are using react, you can make these changes using state. When state of div updates to scroll, change state of pseudoelem to hidden, or not even in the DOM.

Comment: @mhatch can you please update the code. Thank you